# MAMP and Mac Apache Webserver not working

Tags: mysql, apache, mamp

Recently my MAMP and the native Apache web server on my Mac (10.6.8) quit working and do not seem to want to start. I've tried searching all over the web for answers, but can't seem to find any good answers. Several things to note:

1) When I try to start the Apache web server through System Preferences, the console logs the following error:
   - [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
The server then appears to run, but the little green/red/yellow dot on the System Preferences pane stays yellow.

2) MAMP will not initialize at all. I cannot find an my.cnf file anywhere on my computer and the log/error files for both mysql and apache do not exist. I have uninstalled MAMP Pro with the uninstaller and removed the MAMP folder before running a reinstall to see if that solves the problem. This did not seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the missing my.cnf file you need do the following steps in a terminal

1. Open a terminal Window
   Utilities->Terminal
2. Create the missing file

   sudo touch /etc/my.cnf

**N.B.** You will be asked to enter your password.

1. Change the owner of the file

   sudo chown fraki /etc/my.cnf

**N.B.** Replace fraki with your username

With regards to the Apache problem, looks like a bad SSL configuration. I can direct you to how I setup SSL on my MAMP installation for OSX Lion:

http://frankieinguanez.wordpress.com/2012/02/10/configuring-ssl-for-apache-on-os-x-lion-using-mamp/